# ANDROID a single google drive for all users

Tags: android, google-drive-api, drive

i am trying to make a google drive for my app , single google drive that will store all the users (hopefully 1 million) media ( pictures , videos and audio) , i spent two days on researching how to do it , yet i have no clear direction .

if any one know if it's possible and the way to do it , please help me ! 
 it's the final step in my APP :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access Google Drive using a rest api. You could use this to store the user information by dividing the drive into different directories. A more common solution is to use something like firebase.

Comment: firebase is expensive for a media sharing app with 1m users (target) , so i am going for a common drive .
what is the rest api ( i am new to this things) @dazza5000